# Android Studio - How do you get image from gallery and then save it

Tags: image, imageview, save

I have an app that contains a button. when you press the button, the application will send you to your mobile phone's image gallery. you then select the image and it will appear on an imageview above the button. This all goes without a problem but the only bad thing is that when I close and reopen the app. the image is gone. Does anybody know a way to do this?

Here's the code:

```
Button imageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pictureButton);
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(i, 1);
            }
        });
```

this is the button used to open the gallery.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.userPicture);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

        }
```

This is the code tha handles getting the picture and displaying it on the app.

as for how I save data, I am using sharedpreferences for texts, checkboxes and sliders. but it only doesn't work on images.

So what I want is the image to be saved so that when I reopen the application, it gets loaded.

Comment: save the picturePath using sharedPreferences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U could save the picturePath string into a file. A really easy way to do this is by using the [Properties object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html).
Then each time when you open the activity, you open the properties file and read out the path that is saved. Then you can set it again with a part of the code that you allready have.

Comment: Than you so far, it seems that I can save the image now using sharedpreferences. but when I start eh app it is still a string so it shows nothing. I am curious about how properties work but I am not very got at programming. could you perhaps provide me with an example code?

Comment: This is a from a school project of mine. We use this class to save and get the player name. https://github.com/Strate-D/King-of-the-Hill/blob/master/King_of_the_Hill/src/kingofthehill/UI/ApplicationContext.java